# Can't use ibus-mozc ime with IDLE(python)

Tags: python-idle, ime

A project I am attempting to create in python requires the input and output of japanese strings, but the IME I use does not register in IDLE(every time I try to type something, nothing appears on screen.).

Comment: IME = Input Method Editor?  What OS?  Does your IME work with interactive mode python?  Idle uses the tkinter wrapping of the tcl/tk gui framework which receives keystroke events, so the IME and OS must generate key events.  A friend uses the standard Windows IME to enter Japanese in Idle with no problem.

Comment: @terry Ubuntu, what do you mean by interactive mode python?

Comment: When you start python without running a program: `command-line-prompt> python` or run a program with `-i`: `prompt> python -i path/to/file.py so that Idle is not running.